# OpenSSL 3.0: how to enable SSLv3_method (compatibility with legacy system)

Tags: c++, openssl

I need to enable SSLv3_method building OpenSSL c++ in windows in Visual Studio.
I open The VS2015 Native command prompt and I configure project with

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A -no-shared -no-module -enable-ssl3-method
```

the -enable-ssl3-method should enable the SSLv3_method but it doesn't. Where do I wrong?

Comment: Sounds like openssl 3 doesn't support ssl3 https://www.spinics.net/lists/openssl-users/msg14380.html

Comment: Remove the `-` from in front of `no-shared`, `no-module` and `enable-ssl3-method` and add `enable-ssl3`

Comment: @MattCaswell, i tried but did not work

Comment: I build the code, but wireshark capture is "sslv3 record layer: alert handshake failure"